# Azure append policy does not append

Tags: azure

I have a tag append policy which looks like this:

```
{
  "if": {
    "AllOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
      },
      {
        "AnyOf": [
          {
            "field": "tags[SandBox]",
            "exists": "false"
          },
          {
            "field": "tags[CostCenter]",
            "exists": "false"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "append",
    "details": [
      {
        "field": "tags[CostCenter]",
        "value": "APP1234567"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My intention is to apply a cost center tag to all VMs which do not already have sandbox tag. For test I have few VMs where one of the VMs have sandbox tag, one has just bunch of random tags and rest do not have tags at all. Policy finds non-compliant resources just fine but it does not apply the tags. Am I missing something in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy works just fine. I just did not know this:
"Append is used to add additional fields to the requested resource during creation or update."